# How to set referrer for Javascript with awesomium 1.7.4.2

Tags: c#, .net, referrer, awesomium

Trying to set the referrer through a `CustomResourceInterceptor`.

This code does not work:

```
request.AppendExtraHeader("Referer", "somereferrer.com");
```

Header is not sent.

This code works:

```
request.Referrer = "somereferrer.com";
```

Header is sent. BUT referrer receives only the server and can be seen in the server variable `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`. Of javascript referrer does not get in the variable `document.referrer` is empty. Respectively the counters counts both direct transitions.

Got to do so by calling the event `webView.DocumentReady`:

```
webView.ExecuteJavascript("delete window.document.referrer;window.document.__defineGetter__('referrer', function () { return 'somereferrer.com';});");
```

But this is not the right way. This crutch works not always. There must be a way to allocate it correctly.

How to make the referrer passed and the client side too? As it can be properly implemented?